# F# - Visual Studio Debugger - Stepping over causes continue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2015, f#-3.0

I'm currently trying to learn F# and am having some problems with the Visual Studio 2015 debugger. Taking the following code as an example (I'm playing around with ASP.NET Web API):

```
[<Route("api/HomeApi/VideoCapture")>]
[<System.Web.Http.HttpGet>]
member this.VideoCapture() : HttpResponseMessage =
    let response = this.Request.CreateResponse()
    this.SetupCameraConsumers()
    this.SetupCapture()                        
    response.Content <- new PushStreamContent(this.Test())
    response
```

I have put a breakpoint at the first line in this method, stepping over the 'let' works fine, but when I try to step over the next line, VS debugger essentially continues to the end of the method without throwing any errors. Within the `this.SetupCameraConsumers()` call, I am simply adding some objects to a list and returns a 'unit'.

Has anyone come across anything like this before? If I can provide any more information please let me know - I've used the VS debugger for C# code and have never encountered anything like this.

Am I calling a method correctly? Is this allowed in F#?

Thanks!

Comment: Debugging in a functional language is not the same as debugging in a procedural language. In a procedural languages variables are assigned a value, in functional programming items are bound. This is not a bug or unusual. Truthfully when you get proficient with functional programming you will not need to use a debugger. Seriously. I only need to use a debugger when I have state and often go for months without using a debugger with functional programming.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply :) I appreciate you can't give a crash course in functional programming, but is this happening because following the initial 'let' bind, I'm not assigning any more values after this point? Sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's obvious or that it has anything to do with F# being a functional language. **I would expect to be able to step through this code.** VS debugger does show some peculiar behavior when stepping through F# code, but that mostly has to do with parts of code being optimized away or otherwise changed in the resulting IL code in a way that can't be cleanly matched back to the original F# code. This doesn't look like such a case though.

Comment: The code itself looks ok. If it works, I wouldn't dwell on why the debugger acts strange there.

Comment: I've also had the debugger skip over lines unexpectedly while stepping into code.  I have found it helpful to put breakpoints inside functions or other key points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else who may run into this issue, disabling the debugging option 'Just my code' allows me to step over the code. I'm not entirely sure why that should make a difference though. Thanks again for the helpful comments provided.

Comment: In addition, the comment made by @scrwtp I think was also valid regarding optimized code. I had the 'Optimize code' checkbox checked within the Project's build properties. Unchecking this has also helped and I can now debug properly.